# How to determine when/where pointers in .ctors get mapped?

Tags: c++, elf, ghidra, x86-64

So I am learning about ELF, and am looking through a binary in Ghidra as I do. I've made sense of the ELF header, and now I am looking through the program header table.

My binary has a bunch of entries in the program header table, but I am hung up on one in particular...

From referencing...

http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.pheader.html#p_flags

...I can see what the different flags mean. Of relevance:

```
p_offset = 0xABCDEF
p_vaddr = 0x1BCDEF
p_filesz = <number>
p_memsz = <bigger number>
```

I am able to go to the p_vaddr value in the binary, and it brings me to the `.ctors` section. Where I do see what appears to be a list of pointers, but currently those pointers do not represent valid virtual addresses (by currently I mean they are not virtual addresses that I can "go" to in Ghidra). When I run the program dynamically in gdb though, I can run `x addr_of_interest` and it succeeds and says it is pointing to something in a library blah blah.

I found a relevant link from GCC too, but it did not answer my question as far as I could tell...

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Initialization.html

My question therefore is this: **When/how are these pointers mapped to valid memory, and where in the ELF file is the information that would tell me how this happens?**

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are looking at `.ctors` and not, for example, `.got`?

Comment: @igor thanks for clarifying, but yes, I'm sure. There is a (symbol I believe?) In Ghidra displayed as `__CTOR_LIST__` and once you jump there an auto generated comment that says `.ctors`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh. Stupid.

Importantly, the binary I am looking at is **not** a PIE (**P**osition **I**ndependent **E**xecutable). I had Ghidra's image base set to 0x0, rather than 0x400000 (which is the p_vaddr of the loadable segment containing all of the code, and notably, the canonical value used here for x86_64 binaries). This is the only reason the function pointers listed in `.ctors` were not addresses Ghidra could go to. As soon as I set the image base to 0x400000 they were legitimate.

:facepalm: